# Upgrading to React: 15.5.0 causing errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I did a npm install to pull in the latest version of react 15.5.0, however, I'm getting a very cryptic error and now my application doesn't work.  I tried searching and couldn't find anything that related to what I'm seeing. The following is what I'm seeing:

> warning.js:36 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `GridContainer`.
>
> ReactReconciler.js:64 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>       'getHostNode' of null at Object.getHostNode (ReactReconciler.js:64)

For now, I revert back to 15.3.2 but want to understand what is going on.  Because I want to stay current with all the react development and try and fix things right away.  I tried commenting out the code to see if it's a particular component that is causing the issue but no such luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the GirdContainer

```
const GridContainer = ({ onOpen, open, onClose, numDrugSelected }) => (
<div style={{height: '100%'}}>
      <Table>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Hello</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
</div>
);
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8267

Comment: Can we get the code of your GridContainer component?

Comment: Sure, but its just a stateless component.  After I remove that component, thinking it was something wrong with it.  A component in the material-ui library was giving the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out what was happened.  The latest version of material-ui changed some default imports.  So  must be imported via import Table from 'material-ui/Table'  before I had import { Table } from 'material-iu' likewise with Dialog.  For some reason, webpack didn't complain, so I didn't get any transpiler errors. Just runtime errors.  Strange, but I'm back up and running.